# How to use the command \valign in the enumerate environment?

Tags: vertical-alignment

From this question [How to get the height of a minipage to set the height of another one?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/439258/how-to-get-the-height-of-a-minipage-to-set-the-height-of-another-one)
I found useful the answer of @egreg. Is there a way

1. the first column to be aligned at the top?
2. the tikzpicture to be set in the center in relation to the first column?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
    \item
    \valign{#\cr
    \hsize=0.49\linewidth
        Text\newline
        Text\newline
        Text\newline
        Text\newline
    \cr
    \noalign{\hfill}
    \hsize=0.49\linewidth
    \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
                    \draw[->] (-0.75,0) -- (pi,0) node[below] {$x$};
                    \draw[->] (0,-0.5) -- (0,2) node[left] {$y$};
                    \fill (0,0) circle[radius=0.025] node[below left] {$O$};
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \cr
}
    \item
    \valign{#\cr
    \hsize=0.49\linewidth
        Text\newline
        Text\newline
        Text\newline
        Text\newline
        Text\newline
        Text\newline
        Text\newline
        Text\newline
        Text\newline
        Text\newline
        Text\newline
        Text\newline
    \cr
    \noalign{\hfill}
    \hsize=0.49\linewidth
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[->] (-0.75,0) -- (pi,0) node[below] {$x$};
        \draw[->] (0,-0.5) -- (0,2) node[left] {$y$};
        \fill (0,0) circle[radius=0.025] node[below left] {$O$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \cr
}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why don't you use two `minipage`s and align them using the `[c]` alignment?

Comment: I like this way and I want to learn more about the command `\valign`. Also, I tried with two `minipage`s but didn't work as I would prefer.

Comment: Well, it isn't vertically centred as you didn't put a `\vfill` above and below the contents of the two columns (that's the easy part).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `adjustbox`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{lipsum} % for mock text

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
    \item
    \adjustbox{valign=t}{\valign{#\cr
      \hsize=0.49\linewidth
        \lipsum[4][1-2]
    \cr
    \noalign{\hfill}
    \hsize=0.49\linewidth
    \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
                    \draw[->] (-0.75,0) -- (pi,0) node[below] {$x$};
                    \draw[->] (0,-0.5) -- (0,2) node[left] {$y$};
                    \fill (0,0) circle[radius=0.025] node[below left] {$O$};
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \cr
}}
    \item
    \adjustbox{valign=t}{\valign{#\cr
    \hsize=0.49\linewidth
        \lipsum[4][1-2] \lipsum[4][1-2]
        \lipsum[4][1-2] \lipsum[4][1-2]
        \lipsum[4][1-2] \lipsum[4][1-2]
    \cr
    \noalign{\hfill}
    \hsize=0.49\linewidth
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[->] (-0.75,0) -- (pi,0) node[below] {$x$};
        \draw[->] (0,-0.5) -- (0,2) node[left] {$y$};
        \fill (0,0) circle[radius=0.025] node[below left] {$O$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \cr
}}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The following aligns the numbers with the first line of the left column while the two columns are vertically centred to each other. It does so by first typesetting the left column with the alignment on the baseline of the first row via `\vtop` inside a box. Then the `\valign` is moved via `\raisebox`. `-\height` will move the contents completely below the baseline, and `\dp\valignalign@box` will move it up so that the baseline is on the same point as it would for the `\vtop` alone.

To vertically centre the two columns to each other I use `\vfil#\vfil\cr` for the `\valign` preamble. Since basically the same code is used two times, I put it into a macro.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tikz}

\makeatletter
\newsavebox\valignalign@box
\newcommand\valignalign[4]
  {%
    \setbox\valignalign@box\vtop{\hsize=#1\linewidth#2\par}%
    \raisebox{\dimexpr-\height+\dp\valignalign@box\relax}{%
        \valign{\vfil##\vfil\cr
          \hsize=#1\linewidth
          \unvbox\valignalign@box
          \cr
          \noalign{\hfil}%
          \hsize=#3\linewidth
          #4%
          \cr
    }}%
  }
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item
    \valignalign
      {.49}
      {%
        Text\newline
        Text\newline
        Text\newline
        Text\newline
      }
      {.49}
      {%
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
          \draw[->] (-0.75,0) -- (pi,0) node[below] {$x$};
          \draw[->] (0,-0.5) -- (0,2) node[left] {$y$};
          \fill (0,0) circle[radius=0.025] node[below left] {$O$};
        \end{tikzpicture}%
      }%
  \item
    \valignalign
      {.49}
      {%
        Text\newline
        Text\newline
        Text\newline
        Text\newline
        Text\newline
        Text\newline
        Text\newline
        Text\newline
        Text\newline
        Text\newline
      }
      {.49}
      {%
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
          \draw[->] (-0.75,0) -- (pi,0) node[below] {$x$};
          \draw[->] (0,-0.5) -- (0,2) node[left] {$y$};
          \fill (0,0) circle[radius=0.025] node[below left] {$O$};
        \end{tikzpicture}%
      }%
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]