# Footnote text at the bottom of the minipage

Tags: footnotes, minipage

When I put a footnote in a `minipage`, the footnote appears right after the text:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[left=2.00cm, right=3.00cm, top=1.00cm, bottom=1.00cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}
    \begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth}
        Some text here\footnote{with a footnote}
    \end{minipage}\hfill%
    \begin{minipage}{0.45\linewidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
    \end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

I would like it to appear the the bottom of the `minipage`, leaving some space between the normal text and the footnote. Ideally it should align with the bottom of the picture in the right `minipage`.

For normal text outside of a `minipage` I use the package `footmisc` with the option `[bottom]`, but that's not working in the `minipage`, for some reason.

I have also tried [egreg's solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/439266/49347) with `\valign` instead of `minipage`s, but the footnote does not appear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can set a height for the minipage and then stretch the content. I removed inputenc, as utf8 is the default in a current LaTeX.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx,calc}
\usepackage[left=2.00cm, right=3.00cm, top=1.00cm, bottom=1.00cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}
    \begin{minipage}[c][\heightof{\includegraphics[width=0.45\linewidth]{example-image-a}}][s]{0.5\linewidth}
        Some text here\footnote{with a footnote}
    \end{minipage}\hfill%
    \begin{minipage}{0.45\linewidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
    \end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I would have used a savebox and avoided converting the image twice.

Comment: @JohnKormylo yes, would work too, but the actual height isn't the main point of the question and  it is not really clear which height is actually wanted, so I choose a lazy way.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Sorry if the question was not clear, but that's exactly what I wanted. However, doesn't the `[s]` option stretch the text inside the `minipage` vertically so that, if it's any longer than just one line, it will add space between the lines of text as well?

Comment: @JohnKormylo How would you do it with a savebox?

Comment: @Andyc why don't you try?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Right: I read yet another answer by egreg and didn't notice that he put something else besides the `[s]`, which increased line spacing. That's why I thought it was `[s]` that did the trick, but it's not.   By the way, how do you paste the result of the code run? I tried once, but I got a lot of white space and it didn't look good.

Comment: you mean the picture? I use the in-built app of windows to make a screenshot of a part of my screen.